# Creating a file under nested folder in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

What's the best way to create a file under a nested folder in Sharepoint ?
My current method

```
public string CreateSPFile(string spServerURL, string spDocumentLibraryURL, string folder, string fileName, Stream fileStream, bool overwrite)
{
    if (SPSite.Exists(new Uri(spServerURL)))
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite(spServerURL);
        SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb();
        oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPFolder spFolder = oWebsite.Folders[spDocumentLibraryURL];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(folder))
        {
            spFolder.SubFolders[folder].Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, overwrite);
        }
        else
        {
            SPFileCollection files = spFolder.Files;
            spFolder.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, overwrite);
        }
        oWebsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        site.Close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, if I want to create a file under nested folder, i need to modified my codes.
*What will be better way to handle this kind of saving nested folder situation?*

According to my project structure, the file can be like **/DocumentLibrary/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/File.txt.**

Comment: Tip: When you have an if-else that starts with "!", you should always remove the "!" (and ofcourse swap the content of the if and else, for readability :)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it will be better for others.

Comment: @radbyx: I won't suggest this as a general rule. This really depends on the context.

Comment: @Stefan I read it somewere but now I can't find it. I'm not saying I'm right just because I read it though. 
If the "!" in the if dosn't give anything beside harder readability, you should flip the if-else i think. I don't care what people go with, but if someone never thought of this before, it might be usefull.

Comment: @radbyx I don't agree. That is, I write code such that the "positive case" is forward (with few exceptions). In this case the "positive case" is when the string *is not* null-or-empty. (It's actually a double-negative.)

Comment: @pst Good argument, I can see it work if it's consistens. I still prefer as "simple" logic as possible thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load a folder by its server relative URL:

```
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("/DocumentLibrary/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/");
```

With this approach you do not have to load folder by folder and your code works with n folder levels.

I've updated your code sample and added some comments regarding SharePoint best practices:

```
public string CreateSPFile(string spServerURL, string spDocumenttargetUrl, string folder, string fileName, Stream fileStream, bool overwrite)
{
    // I suggest skip this pre check since it internally opens a new site object
    // If you have to silenlty ignore non-existant SPSite you should catch a FileNotFoundException.
    if (SPSite.Exists(new Uri(spServerURL)))
    {
        // use the using construct to safely dispose the opened SPSite object
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(spServerURL))
        {
            // SPWeb object opened with SPSite.OpenWeb() have to be disposed as well
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                string targetUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl, spDocumenttargetUrl);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(folder))
                {
                    targetUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(targetUrl, folder);
                }

                SPFolder target = web.GetFolder(target);

                SPFileCollection files = target.Files;
                target.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, overwrite);

                // no need to revert AllowUnsafeUpdates for newly opened webs
                // web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stefan >> Thanks a lot for your great answer. But I have some question. What do you mean `// I suggest skip this pre check since it internally opens a new site object
    // If you have to silenlty ignore non-existant SPSite you should catch a FileNotFoundException.
` ? I don't know much about SharePoint.  When will I need to revert AllowUnsafeUpdates ?
Thanks again.

Comment: @kevin: `SPSite.Exists()` opens internally a new SPSite object. Calling the constructor `new SPSite(...)` queries the database. If performance is relevant to you, you might want to avoid the overhead that comes with `SPSite.Exists()` and just catch the exception. Regarding `AllowUnsafeUpdates` it's good practice to revert it for objects you do not have control over - you did not open yourself. E.g.: `SPContext.Current.Web`

Answer (score 3):

For uploading a file into a nested folder you could consider the following approach:

- ensure the target folder exist using the method `EnsureFolder` provided below
- upload a file using [SPFileCollection.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414180(v=office.15).aspx)

### How to ensure a nested Folder exist using SharePoint SSOM

```
internal static class SPWebExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensure SPFolder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web"></param>
    /// <param name="listTitle"></param>
    /// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SPFolder EnsureFolder(this SPWeb web, string listTitle, string folderUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderUrl))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folderUrl");
        var list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
        return CreateFolderInternal(list, list.RootFolder, folderUrl);
    }


    private static SPFolder CreateFolderInternal(SPList list, SPFolder parentFolder, string folderUrl)
    {
        var folderNames = folderUrl.Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var folderName = folderNames[0];

        var curFolder =
            parentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault( f => System.String.Compare(f.Name, folderName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
        if (curFolder == null)
        {
            var folderItem = list.Items.Add(parentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                                            folderName);
            folderItem.SystemUpdate();
            curFolder = folderItem.Folder;
        }


        if (folderNames.Length > 1)
        {
            var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderNames, 1, folderNames.Length - 1);
            return CreateFolderInternal(list, curFolder, subFolderUrl);
        }
        return curFolder;
    }
}
```

Gist: [EnsureFolder.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/f604d84d99cd260466b8)

---

The following example demonstrates how to ensure the following folder structure exist under `Documents` library and upload a file into it:

```
Orders
     |
     A --
        |
        A1
```

Example:

```
var targetFolder = web.EnsureFolder("Documents", "Orders3/A/A1");
var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
var fileUrl = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
targetFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, fileContent);
```